# OpenNetCF IPInterfaceProperties.DnsAddresses crashes

Tags: compact-framework, smart-device-framework

I am using OpenNetCF 2.3.0.39 and I am getting a hard crash when try to access the DnsAddresses.Count property. Is anyone familiar with this problem or a workaround?

Dim interfaces As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

For Each ni As NetworkInterface In interfaces

```
Dim ipProps As IPInterfaceProperties = ni.GetIPProperties()

If ipProps.DnsAddresses.Count > 0 Then
```

...

Comment: It works on all of my test devices that I have in-house.  What kind of device are you using?  Can you step through the source and see where the failure is occurring?

Comment: @ctacke the device is a symbol MC70. sorry I didn't see your comment until now.